# Why keycloak-tls isn't disabled in cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I have Helm chart (https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak) config which looks like this:

```
keycloak:
  basepath: auth/
  username: admin
  password: password
  route:
    tls:
      enabled: false
  extraEnv: |
    - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
      value: "true"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
      value: keycloak/master-realm.json
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: >-
        -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
  extraVolumes: |
    - name: realm-secret
      secret:
        secretName: realm-secret
  extraVolumeMounts: |
    - name: realm-secret
      mountPath: "keycloak"
      readOnly: true
  extraArgs: "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/keycloak -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING"
  ingress:
    enabled:    true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    path: /auth/?(.*)
    hosts:
      - keycloak.localtest.me
```

Where `keycloak` is folder within where everything is located with `master-realm.json` configs, where I set `"sslRequired" : "NONE"`

I've setted secret containing master-realm.json in my k8s cluster on creation like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic realm-secret --from-file=./keycloak/master-realm.json
```

And I see it there with:

```
$ kubectl describe secrets/realm-secret
Name:         realm-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
master-realm.json:  62288 bytes
```

But in my ingress controller I still see error and nothing works:

```
W0829 13:44:44.838998       7 controller.go:1387] Error getting SSL certificate "default/keycloak-tls": local SSL certificate default/keycloak-tls was not found
```

How do I disable this keycloak-tls?

Comment: And here is my keycloak server logs https://pastebin.com/yCUW7rNz

Comment: That is how demo realm config looks like https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/blob/master/contrib/local-environment/keycloak/master-realm.json, but with ssl set from "external" to "NONE"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you are deploying helm chart default ingress of keycloak of being created with it and which is pointing and looking for `TLS` secret.

Try listing all ingress and find the default ingress which is using TLS secret.

List ingress by

```
Kubectl get ingress
```

default name would be something similar to

```
{{ .Release.Name }}.keycloak.example.com
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't it from realm json to disable this? I have commited it here for complete config https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/kubernetes-keycloak/tree/master/kubernetes

Comment: Here how ingress looks like https://pastebin.com/PqE9akyg